# PureComponents license problems

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm maintaining a legacy Winforms application that exclusively uses purecomponents [PureComponents via waybackmachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20150219011402/http://www.purecomponents.com/) for all its controls. Unfortunately the provider of these controls disappeared from the web Feb 2015 so I cannot seek support from them.

My problem is that with some versions of the compiled application, I get the error message "PureComponents EntrySet Evaluation has expired. Features are disabled. If you have already licensed the product, please make sure you use Runtime key to license the product properly."

I've checked that the license keys are correct and I'm registering them on application startup:

```
PureComponents.ActionSet.Licensing.RunTimeLicenseKey = "xxxx"
```

I'd very much appreciate any advice as I'm stumped on this and unlikely to find much in the way of support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a licensing mechanism and not about programming

Comment: Is there a 'licenses.licx' file in your project's Properties folder?  That is where those keys sometimes have to go.  Or at least proper refs to the controls in question.

Comment: Thanks DonBoitnott, that was the problem. I've copied the .lic files to the My Documents folder and that's fixed the issue.